# Clojure Atom Doesn't Update When Wrapped in Defined Function

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Not sure what is going on here, but I have this code, where the map function successfully executes in my repl without being wrapped in a defined function:

```
(def dogs '({:name "scout" :age 5} {:name "rux" :age 3} {:name "fenley" :age 2}))

(def ages (atom {:above-four '() :below-four '()}))

(map
    #(if (> (get-in % [:age]) 4)
         (swap! ages update-in [:above-four] merge %)
         (swap! ages update-in [:below-four] merge %)) dogs)

@ages
=> {:above-four ({:name "scout", :age 5}), :below-four ({:name "fenley", :age 2} {:name "rux", :age 3})}
```

Yet, when I define the map function as such:

```
(def ages (atom {:above-four '() :below-four '()}))

(def dogs '({:name "scout" :age 5} {:name "rux" :age 3} {:name "fenley" :age 2}))

(defn test-dogs []
    (map
    #(if (> (get-in % [:age]) 4)
         (swap! ages update-in [:above-four] merge %)
         (swap! ages update-in [:below-four] merge %)) dogs)
         @ages)
```

I get the following result:

```
=> {:above-four (), :below-four ()}
```

I'm very confused, because this function taken straight from the Clojure docs works just fine:

```
(def m1 (atom {:a "A" :b "B"}))

(defn update-m1 []
    (swap! m1 assoc :a "Aaay")
    @m1)

=> {:a "Aaay", :b "B"}
```

Comment: Show exactly how you're calling `test-dogs`. I suspect this is because of `map`'s laziness. If you change the `map` to a `doseq`, does it fix it?

Comment: Also, there really isn't any reason to use `atom`s here. They're just going to slightly complicate matters.

Comment: Need to use an atom because this is a simplified example of a larger program where it's needed. Doseq returns CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: doseq requires a vector for its binding in spam-problem.core:2

Comment: You need to use the proper syntax for `doseq`. For this test though actually, just change `map` to `mapv`.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked.

Comment: If you show exactly how you were calling `test-dogs`, I can write a proper answer to show you what was wrong.

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought I'd written that. Was calling it like this (test-dogs).

Comment: Well, I know that, but if you were using a REPL, you must have had something after `(test-dogs)`. A call to `println` perhaps?

Comment: You mean when I used map not being wrapped in a defined function? If that's you mean, I just entered @ages after. No print statement or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `test-dogs` uses `map`, it returns a *lazy sequence*. The elements of lazy sequences aren't realized until they're needed.

The problem with your set up is you're trying to use `map` to run a side effect (the call to `swap!`; an impure action), and never actually use the result of `map`. Because you never request results from `map`, the mapping function containing `swap!` never runs.

By using `mapv` (which returns a non-lazy vector), or `doseq` (which is meant to carry out side effects):

```
(doseq [dog dogs]
  (let [k (if (> (:age dog) 4)
                :above-four
                :below-four)]

     (swap! ages update k merge dog)))
```

You can force the side effects to run.

I cleaned up the code a bit. The `-in` versions you were using were unnecessary; as was the the call to `get-in`. I also got rid of the redundant calls to `swap!`.

Note though that at least in your example, use of `atom`s is entirely unnecessary. Even if you have a more complicated use case, make sure their use is justified. Mutable variables just aren't as common in languages like Clojure.